# Ubuntu 22.04 terminal window closes on error

Tags: gnome-terminal, 22.04

Since upgrading to 22.04 I have windows close very regularly (not always) when a process exits with anything apart from 0. It happens on my host and in freshly installed and updated vbox guests. Google didn't turn up anything. How can I go back to it not doing this?

Comment: Can you add a reproducible example?

Comment: @Raffa that is going to be almost impossible. It mostly seems to happen with docker errors but not only. It also doesn't *always* happen. I will execute something, the window disappears, I execute again and it works. Initially I thought it was a tmux problem but I am testing out some stuff in a fresh vbox guest and it is happening with plain terminal also.